# Custom app background on launch image [ios 4 & 5]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, hig

my iOS application has the option to change the background image, there are 3 different background patterns available, and the user can select any of them.

The problem is the launch image, reading the iOS HIG it is supposed to be an image similar to the GUI (first 'window') of the application. Is it possible to load a different image depending on a user prefference (the background pattern selected)?

Thanks!

Comment: Many apps don't follow the Apple guidelines in this regard, and instead use"splash screen" type graphics, logos, etc. for their launch images. You can likely do whatever you want. For your needs, use a generic launch image and then in applicationDidFinishLaunching, use the user's prefs to load the graphic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do so - you can only have one default.png, and you can't alter it programmatically before the app starts. I'd recommend simply creating a splash screen different from the app's background. Note that the iOS HIG is a *Guideline* not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  Default.png needs to be set when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the Launch Image during app launch (or anytime during App execution).  The way to handle this (realizing that you might be violating the HIG) is to present your own image directly after `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and leave the Launch Image as either an intermediate image or blank.